# Julia and big numbers

Tags: julia, precision, biginteger

How does Julia compute big numbers?

For example, this works as expected:

```
julia> 10^18
1000000000000000000
```

But for bigger numbers, there is a problem with integers:

```
julia> 10^19
    -8446744073709551616 

 julia> 10^20
     7766279631452241920
```

But it works if a decimal number is used:

```
julia> 10.0^20
1.0e20
```

Do you know why?

Comment: You've got a very good answer already. I just thought I'd add that the behaviour you're observing in the question has nothing to do with Julia *per se*. The difference between 64 bit integers and 64 bit floating points is common to pretty much every language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this documentation page: https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/

As you can see, Int64 have a max length of: **2^63 - 1 ~ 1.0 * 10^19**
So your 10^19 is greater than this max value. That's why there is a problem. 
You can try to convert your 10 to another type.

`10.0^20` works because `10.0` is a float, so it has a superior max value.

If you want unlimited precision for integers, you can use `BigInts`:

```
julia> BigInt(10)^100
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: What is the maximum value for type, BigInt?